# Is this syntax illegal?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, name-lookup

The following will not compile on GCC 4.8.1:

```
//struct Tag {};  // Program compiles if I use this.

template <typename T>
struct Base {
    struct Tag {};
    Base(Tag) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
    Derived(Tag tag) : Base<T>(tag) {}
//  Derived(Base<T>::Tag tag) : Base<T>(tag) {}
};

int main() {}
```

complaining [Error] expected ')' before 'tag'.  It compiles on Visual Studio 2013 though, and I wanted to know if VS2013 is correct in accepting it.  It does compile when I declare `Tag` outside of `Base<T>`, but I want to declare `Tag` inside of `Base<T>` where it belongs.  Using `Derived(Base<T>::Tag tag) : Base<T>(tag) {}` didn't help either.  Any way to fix the above so that both compilers accept this, while keeping `Tag` inside of `Base<T>`.

Comment: Your code is compiling fine with Visual Studio.

Comment: I know, I stated that.  But I want it to compile on both compilers.  So you are saying that the syntax is legal?

Comment: Use `Derived(typename Base<T>::Tag tag) : Base<T>(tag) {}`, because `Base<T>` is a dependant name

Comment: Ah great!  Thank you.  Problem solved.  But I'm still wondering if the original code is legal or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[temp.dep]/3:

> In the definition of a class or class template, **if a base class
>   depends on a template-parameter, the base class scope is not examined
>   during unqualified name lookup** either at the point of definition of
>   the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class
>   template or member.

`Tag` is used as an unqualified name - thus it can never designate the member of a depedent base class. However, `Tag` is also not dependent, so lookup must be resolved at definition time (prior to instantiation), which makes the program ill-formed. That can be diagnosed at either definition or instantiation time.

However, when the name is dependent (like `Base<T>::Tag`), name lookup is postponed and considers members of dependent base classes at instantiation time.